# Membership in 1, 5, 2, 13, 10, ... (recursively defined sequence)

Tags: algorithms, recursion

Find if a given integer is in the series $1, 5, 2, 13, 10, \dots$ in the most efficient way, where the sequence is given by
$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
1 & n=1, \\
2f(\tfrac{n}{2})+3 & n \text{ even}, \\
2f(\tfrac{n-1}{2}) & n>1 \text{ odd}.
\end{cases}
$$

The series is infinite of course, and $x$ can be a number with at most 9 digits. The idea is not to hardcode this and maybe find some kind of correlation that will allow you to solve this fast. I want to say that I have an idea of how to solve it but I don't.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. It may be for the better this sequence looks too simple for the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1,5,2,13,10,7,4,29). What if you stare at a few elements more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence contains all positive integers not divisible by 3. Let us prove this by induction.

Suppose first that $x$ is divisible by 3, and $f(n) = x$. Considering the definition, we see that $x = 2f(n/2) + 3$, and so $f(n/2) = \tfrac{x-3}{2}$, which is also divisible by 3. By induction, this is impossible.

Suppose next that $x>0$ is not divisible by 3. If $x=1$ then $x$ appears in the sequence since $f(1) = 1$, so we can assume that $x \geq 2$. We now consider two cases: $x$ even and $x$ odd.

If $x$ is even then $\tfrac{x}{2}<x$ is positive not divisible by 3, and so by induction, $\tfrac{x}{2} = f(m)$ for some $m$. Then $f(2m) = x$.

Similarly, if $x$ is odd then $\tfrac{x-3}{2} < x$ is not divisible by 3. Furthermore, since $x \geq 5$, it is furthermore positive. By induction, $\tfrac{x-3}{2} = f(m)$ for some $m$. Then $f(2m+1) = x$.